# Winston logger cli method is not working

Tags: logging, command-line-interface, winston

I am trying CLI mehtod on my logger instance for pretty printing , but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var logger = new winston.Logger({
transports: [

     new winston.transports.File({
        level: info
        filename: 'filename',
        json: true,
        name: 'all-log-file',
        colorize: true,
        prettyPrint: true
    })
 ]
});

logger.cli();
```

But this is not working for me.Expected output format is like following:

```
 info:   Found existing dependencies
 data:   {
 data:     colors: '0.x.x',
 data:     eyes: '0.1.x',
 data:     findit: '0.0.x',
 data:     npm: '1.0.x',
 data:     optimist: '0.2.x',
 data:     semver: '1.0.x',
 data:     winston: '0.2.x'
 data:   }
 info:   Analyzing dependencies...
 info:   Done analyzing raw dependencies
 info:   Retrieved packages from npm
 warn:   No additional dependencies found
```

I want pretty printed, colorized output, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try console transport?

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            level: 'debug',
            filename: 'prettylog.txt',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: true,
            timestamp: true,
            prettyPrint: true
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false
});
```

Now, you have to show the content using a standard Unix utility:
**cat prettylog.txt**

Comment: Thanks A.DIMO for the help. However I am looking to make it work for file transport. Is it possible using Winston ?

Comment: Actually I am using the windows machine :(

Comment: If you have installed msysgit (aka Git for Windows), you could use BASH emulation.